# Python ctypes: the type of elements in a ctype array

Tags: python, ctypes

I have created in Python a ctype array in the following way:

```
list_1 = [10, 12, 13]
list_1_c = (ctypes.c_int * len(list_1))(*list_1)
```

When I do a print of the first element of list_1_c I get:

```
print list_1_c[0]
10
```

My question is why I don't get the result?

```
c_long(10)
```

If I do:

```
a = ctypes.c_int(10)
print a
```

I get

```
c_long(10)
```

I would have expected that the elements of the array list_1_c to be ctypes elements.

Comment: "I would have expected that the elements of the array list_1_c to be ctypes elements" Obviously, that is not the case - so what is your question? Why this does not behave differently? How this behaves the way it does? What are the advantages and disadvantages? How to get typed elements?

Comment: My question is: Why the elements of the array are not of type c_int?

Comment: Because it is more efficient. Because there is only the array, no elements. Because the array stores values. Because it was implemented this way. Because... Which kind of answer do you seek?

Comment: I thought the elements of the array I created will be of type c_ints. I had a function that worked with ctype structs. And I have passed to it elements of the array I created. It crashed because it tried to get the sizeof the element. So first I thought that was something wrong with the function because I presumed that the elements of the array where of type c_int but they were not. So is just a curiosity of why the elements store are not ctypes that I thought it had an explanation.

Comment: If is because is more efficient I can accept that answer or an explanation on how Python stores elements in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values are stored internally as a C integer array of 3 elements, wrapped in a ctypes array class.  Indexing the array returns Python integers as a convenience.  If you derive a class from `c_int` you can suppress that behavior:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> list_1 = [10, 12, 13]
>>> list_1_c = (ctypes.c_int * len(list_1))(*list_1)
>>> list_1_c  # stored a C array
<__main__.c_long_Array_3 object at 0x00000246766387C8>
>>> list_1_c[0]  # Reads the C int at index 0 and converts to Python int
10
>>> class x(ctypes.c_int):
...  pass
...
>>> L = (x*3)(*list_1)
>>> L
<__main__.x_Array_3 object at 0x00000246766387C8>
>>> L[0]  # No translation to a Python integer occurs
<x object at 0x00000246783416C8>
>>> L[0].value  # But you can still get the Python value
10
```

The reason for the convenience is you can't do much with a wrapped C-types value unless you you access its `.value`:

```
>>> ctypes.c_int(5) * 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'c_long' and 'int'
>>> ctypes.c_int(5).value * 5
25
```